# What's the function of ~には in 「おやには長生きしてもらいたいとおもう」?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は

> おや**には**長生きしてもらいたいとおもう

Please help understand the `には` construct.
Is it a form of emphasis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

“には” = 格助詞 “に” + 係助詞 “は”

係助詞 “は” is emphasis.
In your example, “おやに” is emphasized.